# Prevent css inheritance in Angular Material md-autocomplete

Tags: css, angular-material2

I have the following css:

```
 .form input{
-moz-box-shadow: inset 10px 10px 0px -7px #ededed;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 10px 10px 0px -7px #ededed;
box-shadow: inset 10px 10px 0px -7px #ededed;}
```

But I don't want the md-autocomplete input box to inherit the style.
How do I prevent it from happening?

Comment: There is almost no need to vendor-prefix `box-shadow`.

Comment: I can't change it without messing with the layout... I am just doing vode maintenance

Comment: Just a typo, I meant code

Answer (score 1):

I just had to assign an ID to the md-autocomplete and use the following css

```
#chip input{
border: 0px;
height: 35px;
-moz-box-shadow: 0px;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 0px #ededed;
box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 0px #ededed;
color: #9e9e9e;
outline: none;
```

}